# TypeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute '__getitem__'?

Tags: python, csv

Here is my code so far:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('new_file.txt','r'),delimiter=' ')
row1 = reader[0]
row2 = reader[1]
row3 = reader[2]
```

Here is my `new_file.txt`:

```
this is row one
this is row two
this is row three
```

When I run It i have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/Documents/folder/file.py", line 211, in <module>
    row1 = reader[0]
TypeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

How can I fix that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A `csv.reader()` object is *not* a sequence. You cannot access rows by index.

You'd have to 'slurp' the whole iterable into a list for that:

```
rows = list(reader)
row1 = rows[0]
row2 = rows[1]
row3 = rows[2]
```

This is generally not a good idea. You can instead ask for the next value from the iterator with the [`next()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

```
reader = csv.reader(open('new_file.txt','r'),delimiter=' ')
row1 = next(reader)
row2 = next(reader)
row3 = next(reader)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can loop the `reader` and then access the `row` elements:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('new_file.txt','r'),delimiter=' ')
for row in reader:
    row1 = row[0]
    row2 = row[1]
    row3 = row[3]
```